# If 2 particles produce a potential equal to $\frac{k}{r}$ for each position $r$, how can I deal with the infinities from self-energies?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, singularities, self-energy

Sorry if the title is a bit floppy. I am studying two particle systems and their energy. I was given that (equation 1):
$$\mathbf F=-\mathbf \nabla U.$$
For a potential $U$, which is the same for every particle. My instinct tells me that to find $U$, I can, for example, write it as:
$$U(\mathbf r)=\frac{k_1}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_1|} + \frac{k_2}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_2|}$$
Where $\mathbf r_n$ denotes the position of the $n$-th particle. However, when I try to evaluate the force exerted on particle 2 by using (equation 1) I get division by 0. How can I fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate a potential at a point in space, you do it for all the particles other than the one at that position. The particle at that position is your test particle.

For an $n$-particle system, we could then write the potential at the point of test particle $j$ as:

$$ U_j = \sum_{i = 1, i \ne j}^n \frac{k}{|\vec{r_j} - \vec{r_i}|}$$

And the total potential of the system would be the sum over all $j$. You can of course then use this to figure out the forces.

Why we omit the particle itself makes sense when we think of it as forces since a test particle (point mass) does not exert any force on itself, the force it feels comes only from the other particles in the system.

Comment: The problem is that the book I'm using mentions that "There is a _single_ potential energy function, from which we can derive both forces". You are creating a potential for each particle in the system (U_j) while the book shows just U. ???

Comment: If you have "John R. Taylor - Classical Mechanics" please go to page 138 an onwards. That section is KILLING me.

Comment: @FranciscoRusso that $U$ does give "both forces" from both particles, but it is not valid for calculating forces on the particles themselves, for the reason fhorrobin gave -- it's only valid for calculating forces on additional test particles that might enter the field.

Comment: The reason why the single potential gives both forces is because of Newton's third law. Since the force on one particle is negative the force on the other we can take the gradient wrt the coordinate of the desired particle to find the force from the total potential. This is specifically because we are dealing with a potential that depends only on the separation and not on the locations of the particles themselves.